# BeautifulSoup - не могу найти тег по имени класса

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть сайт, содержащий список шаблонов документов. Надо его распарсить.

Пишу простейшую программу:

```
# Библиотеки для скрапинга
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Начальный URL
url = 'https://uristhome.ru/document'

# Делаем запрос и получаем html
html_text = requests.get(url).text

# Парсим HTML  в дерево тегов
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

# Ищем строки таблицы
table_rows = soup.findAll('li')
#table_rows = soup.findAll(class_="ln-а")
#table_rows = soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class':'ln-a'})

print(f"Найдено {len(table_rows)} строк в таблице")
```

То, что написано после *# Ищем строки таблицы* (это строки 15-18) должно, по идее, выбирать те теги *li*, которые меня интересуют. Но получается, что ничего, кроме самого простого варианта, не работает.

Если раскомментровать строку 15, то поиск по имени тега отработает и выдасться:

```
Найдено 4049 строк в таблице
```

Однако мне нужна более точная выборка. А три оставшиеся варианты дают пустой результат:

```
Найдено 0 строк в таблице
```

Делаю всё, вроде бы, как в разных примерах, но ничего не получается. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно сначала найти список, а в нём уже искать элементы и нужные ссылки. Скорее всего класс `ln-а` подставляется с помощью JS во время загрузки страницы, по этому парсер не может ничего найти (так как он скачал только html). Для полной прогрузки страницы можно использовать `selenium`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

# Ищем список
list_ = soup.find("ul", class_="y_articles-document-list")
# Ищем элементы списка
list_elements = list_.findAll("li")
# Поиск по всему списку
links_1 = list_.findAll("a", class_="rubr") 
# Поиск по элементам списка
links_2 = [element.find("a", class_="rubr") for element in list_elements]
# Получение текста и ссылок
data = [{"text": link.text, "url": link.get("href")} for link in links_2]
print(data)
```

Пример с `selenium`

```
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver  # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  # pip install webdriver-manager


with webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())) as driver:  # Открываем хром
    driver.get("https://uristhome.ru/document")  # Открываем страницу
    time.sleep(5)  # Время на прогрузку страницы
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')  # Получаем готовый html и парсим его

list_ = soup.find("ul", class_="y_articles-document-list")
list_elements = list_.findAll("li", class_="ln-а")
# links_1 = list_.findAll("a", class_="rubr")
# links_2 = [element.find("a", class_="rubr") for element in list_elements] 
# data = [{"text": link.text, "url": link.get("href")} for link in links_1]
```

Comment: Вариант со списком я пробовал, но эффекта не обнаружил.

Я подозревал, что дело именно в динамических элементах, но не представлял, как это побороть. Поставил пакеты selenium и webdriver_manage и попытался запустить новый вариант программы.  К сожалению, выдаёт ошибку: *TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'*. Поскольку selenium не знаю совсем, то смысл понять не могу. Не подскажете?

Comment: 1) В варианте со списком я просто закомментировал нужные строчки. Сейчас поправил. В варианте с `selenium` вам нужна версия 4.x (у меня `selenium-4.1.3` => `pip install selenium==4.1.3`)

Comment: "В варианте со списком". - Действительно - работает! Но я так ничего и не понял. А как же динамические подгружаемые JavaScript ?! Ведь этот вариант ничего нового не использует, просто более строго реализует тот же алгоритм, теми же функциями...

Comment: Проверил версии установленных пакетов: webdriver-manager: Version: 3.5.4   

selenium Version: 3.14.0  До четвёрки явно не дотягивает... Снёс дефаультовую библиотеку, поставил руками 4.1.3 и программа заработала. Охренеть - открылся хром, что-то там забегало, застучало и чего-то выдалось :-)  Буду завтра разбираться. Большое Вам спасибо !

Comment: JS просто добавляет к элементам списка класс, а сам список генерируется на сервере и приходит уже с данными. Чтобы убедится в этом можете вывести `list_` (`print(list_)`). Там будут `li`, но без класса. + этот способ не теряет точность, так как мы скачала ищем конкретный список, а в нём уже нужные нам данные. Таким же образом можно искать в любых тегах. Объект, найденный на странице с помощью `soup.find`, превращается в почти такой же soup, в котором тоже можно искать.

Comment: В данном случае `selenium` использовать можно, но излишне. Его обычно используют, чтобы скроллить страницу и получать динамически-генерируемые данные, которые появляются на странице только когда пользователь прокручивает до низа страницы

Answer (score 2):

```
table_rows = soup.findAll('a', class_="rubr")
for i in table_rows:
    print(i.text)
    print(f'''https://uristhome.ru{i['href']}''')
```

Comment: Всё работает отлично!

Comment: Но мне непонятно вот что: Почему Ваш вариант *table_rows = soup.findAll('a', class_="rubr")* работает, а мой: *table_rows = soup.findAll('li', class_="ln-а")* не работает?! Где-то я читал, что недопустимо использование имён классов с 'минусом' внутри. А можно это как-то обойти? Ведь такое встречается сплошь и рядом..

Comment: Исходный код страницы посмотрите. "что недопустимо использование имён классов с 'минусом' внутр" по сути это не минус, а тире или дефис.