# Парсинг табличных данных

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://news.mail.ru/currency/src/CBRF/charcode/USD/'
data = requests.get(url).text
block = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
heads = block.find('tbody', class_='sc-fvxzrP DXNGm').find_all('tr', class_='sc-jQrDum klKPSx')
for i in heads:
    print(i.text)
```

При запуске кода выдает ошибку:  heads = block.find('tbody', class_='sc-fvxzrP DXNGm').find_all('tr', class_='sc-jQrDum klKPSx')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
Подскажите в чем причина ошибки?

Comment: сайт динамический используйте селениум

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selenium` - решение. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1405047/beautifulsoup-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0/1405101#1405101) я довольно понятно объяснил

```
import bs4
import time
from selenium import webdriver  # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  # pip install webdriver-manager


with webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())) as driver:  # Открываем хром
    driver.get("https://news.mail.ru/currency/src/CBRF/charcode/USD/")  # Открываем страницу
    time.sleep(5)  # Время на прогрузку страницы
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find("tbody", class_="sc-fvxzrP DXNGm"))
```